# develop depression?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

why this phrase such as "Broca's aphasics also develop depression late on" is used by using "DEVELOP"?

what I can guess is depression has several numbers of processes, so that's why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the transitive usage of the verb ***[develop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/develop)*** means:

> - To become affected with; contract: developed a rash; developed agoraphobia. (AHD)

Answer (score 0):

Broca's aphasia is also called agrammatical aphasia, and it's caused by brain damage that destroys the patients ability to use grammar to form sentences.  Speech is limited to disjointed words.  Cognition is usually not lost, and patients who recover report that they knew what they wanted to say but were unable to express their thoughts.  You can see how frustrating this must be, so it's not unreasonable that sufferers would eventually succumb to depression.

Depression may have several different presentations, but your sentence says that prolonged experience with Broca's aphasia leads to depression.